# Unknown argument "excludedFieldIds" on field "serialize" of type "Query"

Tags: sitecore-cli

[image]Where can I find the `excludedFieldIds` argument?

How to resolve?[image]

**Unknown argument "excludedFieldIds" on field "serialize" of type "Query".(GraphQLException)**

**the error is for "excludedFieldId" not "excludedField"
My Sitecore.json has "excludedFields": []**

**STACK TRACE**

```
One or more errors occurred.(AggregateException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<CreateParallelQuery>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<GetTreeNodesInternal>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<Initialize>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.<Initialize>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.SyncSVSItems.ViewModels.SyncSVSItemsViewModel.<<DoRefresh>b__71_0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available.(CheckGraphQLAvailabilityException)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<RunQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.<MakeAuthenticatedRequestInternal>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.<MakeAuthenticatedRequest>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Models.EnvironmentConfiguration.<MakeAuthenticatedRequest>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<RunQuery>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<ExecuteSingleBatchQuery>d__22`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: NotFound(GraphQLHttpException)
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.<ReadHttpResponseMessageAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.<PostAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<RunQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Matched module configurations: itmmfiles
Start processing HTTP request POST https://local.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Sending HTTP request POST https://local.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Received HTTP response after 133.0481ms - OK
End processing HTTP request after 133.2313ms - OK
Refresh Failed
One or more errors occurred.(AggregateException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<CreateParallelQuery>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<GetTreeNodesInternal>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<Initialize>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.<Initialize>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.SyncSVSItems.ViewModels.SyncSVSItemsViewModel.<<DoRefresh>b__71_0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Unknown argument "excludedFieldIds" on field "serialize" of type "Query".(GraphQLException)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<RunQuery>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<ExecuteSingleBatchQuery>d__22`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Matched module configurations: home
Start processing HTTP request POST https://prod-cm.cms.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Sending HTTP request POST https://prod-cm.cms.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Received HTTP response after 977.3587ms - NotFound
End processing HTTP request after 977.401ms - NotFound
Refresh Failed
One or more errors occurred.(AggregateException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<CreateParallelQuery>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<GetTreeNodesInternal>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<Initialize>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.<Initialize>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.SyncSVSItems.ViewModels.SyncSVSItemsViewModel.<<DoRefresh>b__71_0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available.(CheckGraphQLAvailabilityException)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<RunQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.<MakeAuthenticatedRequestInternal>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Authentication.OidcAuthenticationProvider.<MakeAuthenticatedRequest>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Configuration.Models.EnvironmentConfiguration.<MakeAuthenticatedRequest>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<RunQuery>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<ExecuteSingleBatchQuery>d__22`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Unexpected HttpResponseMessage with code: NotFound(GraphQLHttpException)
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.<ReadHttpResponseMessageAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at GraphQL.Client.Http.Internal.GraphQLHttpHandler.<PostAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<RunQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Matched module configurations: home
Start processing HTTP request POST https://local.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Sending HTTP request POST https://local.mm.com/sitecore/api/management
Received HTTP response after 27.5542ms - OK
End processing HTTP request after 27.6783ms - OK
Refresh Failed
One or more errors occurred.(AggregateException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<CreateParallelQuery>d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<GetTreeNodesInternal>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<Initialize>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.<Initialize>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at SVS.VSIX.Serivces.SVSService.<DiscoverSyncCommandsAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at SVS.VSIX.SyncSVSItems.ViewModels.SyncSVSItemsViewModel.<<DoRefresh>b__71_0>d.MoveNext()Inner Exception:
Unknown argument "excludedFieldIds" on field "serialize" of type "Query".(GraphQLException)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.SitecoreApiClient.<RunQuery>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<ExecuteSingleBatchQuery>d__22`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Which Sitecore CLI version have you installed?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am running into the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

The **excluded fields** feature is available from ***CLI*** 4.0 or later.

> https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sitecore-content-serialization-structural-overview.html

If you don't want the feature in your module.json as well as Sitecore.json file. Try using a lower version or try adding fields as mentioned in the link.

Comment: the error is for "excludedFieldId" not "excludedField"

My Sitecore.json has "excludedFields": []

Comment: I have added pic of my sitecore.json file that shows I have excludedFields

Comment: Did you try removing the excludedField[] from Sitecore.json file and execute it?

Comment: Yes,  i already tried removing excludedField[] from Sitecore.json file ...  Same error.

The issue seems to be with GraphQLException

Unknown argument "excludedFieldIds" on field "serialize" of type "Query".(GraphQLException)

where does GraphQL expect to find excludedField ?

Comment: where does GraphQL expect to find "serialize" field? – 
A

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me maybe you haven't got the latest Sitecore Management Services module installed on your environment.

If you're using Docker locally you may have something like this in your .env file:

[image: Docker env file]

Make sure this is using version at least version 4.0.0 and not an old version of the module.