# Running Sitecore 10 CLI command Error "dotnet sitecore ser push -p" getting the attached error

Tags: sitecore-cli

When I am running `Sitecore 10 CLI` command `dotnet sitecore ser push -p` getting the following error.

```
dotnet sitecore ser push -p
Unhandled exception: System.Exception: Unhandled exception
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The request failed. The operation was canceled.) (The request failed. The operation was canceled.) (The request failed. The operation was canceled.) (The request failed. The operation was canceled.) (The request failed. The operation was canceled.) (The request failed. The operation was canceled.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The request failed. The operation was canceled.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.CreateParallelQuery[T](String parallelQueryFragment, TreeScope scope, ItemSpec[] specs, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.GetTreeNodesInternal(IEnumerable`1 itemSpecs, TreeScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.TreeSyncOperation.Initialize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization.Tasks.TreeSyncOperationExecutor.ExecuteTreeSyncOperation(TreeSyncOperation operation, Boolean whatIf, Boolean performValidation, SyncDirection direction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization.Tasks.SyncTask.Execute(SyncTaskOptions options)
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization.Commands.SyncCommandBase.Handle(SyncTask task, SyncArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleInternal(TArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 75
 ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: The request failed. The operation was canceled.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #2) System.InvalidOperationException: The request failed. The operation was canceled.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #3) System.InvalidOperationException: The request failed. The operation was canceled.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---

 ---> (Inner Exception #4) System.InvalidOperationException: The request failed. The operation was canceled.
   at Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.Datasources.Sc.Query.SitecoreTreeDataStore.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<<CreateParallelQuery>b__0>d.MoveNext()<---


   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleExceptionMessageConsoleLogging(Exception exception, ILogger logger) in C:\B   at Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility.Subcommands.SubcommandBase`2.HandleInternal(TArgs args) in C:\BA\ca7111d945a16af4\src\Sitecore.Devex.Client.Cli.Extensibility\Subcommands\SubcommandBase.cs:line 81
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.CommandHandler.GetResultCodeAsync(Object value, InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__20_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<<UseVersionOption>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<UseTypoCorrections>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseParseDirective>b__19_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseDebugDirective>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<RegisterWithDotnetSuggest>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Are you using "excludedfields": [] argument in your <filename>.schema.json?

Comment: try running command with -t -v to see more details dotnet sitecore ser push -p -t -v

Comment: @SumitBhatia where can find the file you have mentioned <filename>.schema.json?

Comment: @Mamtha Check this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30663/unknown-argument-excludedfieldids-on-field-serialize-of-type-query

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes
"excludedFields": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "Configure base fields filter",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/FieldFilter"
          }
        }

Comment: @SuryaNarayan i tried the command which you gave and its failing after [master] FSIndex: Loaded filesystem indices in 4562ms (15120 metadatas)

Comment: @Mamtha Did you check that article and see if is it a CLI version issue?

Comment: @SumitBhatia I check that i have update the version to 4.2.0 but still execution is stopping after a certain point

Comment: What is the exact version of Sitecore and installed management service module in CM? CLI version 4.2.0 was released yesterday. It had some deployment issues and later it was [resolved](https://sitecorechat.slack.com/archives/C0KRE14V9/p1651172336522889?thread_ts=1651168548.296479&cid=C0KRE14V9). It is worth to clear your local CLI folder and try again.